# What does it mean to integrate a vector function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

What is the meaning of a vector function and what is the geometric interpretation of integrating such a function?

Comment: if $f$ is continuous $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ then $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is the vector such that it's $k$ th coefficient is $\int_a^b f_k(x) dx$. where it becomes more complicated is when $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, in that case you have to define path/contour integrals for integrating over a curve, and possibly measures and differential forms when integrating over a surface/volume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Integration of a vector function is an ambiguous term, it may mean a lot of completely different integrals.

1. integral of a vector function over an independent scalar parameter, $\int \vec{v}\,dt$ is simply 3 integrals for each component. Example: integration of velocity to get position in space.
2. integral of a vector function over a path: $\int \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{r}$. This integrates the contribution of a vector field along a path, for instance, work as integral of force along a path, Faraday's law (induction) and Ampere's law, circulation in hydrodynamics and so on.
3. integral of a vector function over a surface: $\iint \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{S}$. This tells you the flux of the vector field through a surface. For instance, actual flux of liquid for velocity field, magnetic flux (relevant for induction) and so on.

2 and 3 satisfy special relations (for potential field, (2) gives you zero for closed loop,  for sourceless field, (3) gives zero for closed surface,...) - check out Stokes and Gauss laws.

There are other less common options... but the essence is, you have to know what your vector is (is it simply a vector variable? is it defined everywhere in space - a field?), and what your expression means. Usually in physics, it's just one of the natural laws in general form when you get from local to global expression.

Comment: What if we want to integrate a scalar-valued function which takes in multivariable input?

Comment: @information_interchange Those are just standard multiple integrals, the number of variables doesn't change much, you just have to choose the integration domain. You can integrate along a curve (you usually parameterize the curve with $t$ and integrate), a surface (parameterize with two parameters), a volume, or any complicated object you want. Integration of scalars can be understood as averaging (you get average value multiplied by domain size), or adding up to a "total amount" (e.g. mass from integration of density/surface density/linear density).

Answer (score 2):

Vector function in 3d space is used to represent a function, and a function in three variables.

Velocity is the integration of acceleration function which can be represented as a vector function in space. This integration can be done if the functions along x y and z co-ordinates are parameteized.

So integrating the acceleration vector function here gives you again a vector function which is velocity and you can interpret speed from this function.